# i can't understand cast for variable listener

Tags: c

What does the type void(**)(void) mean?

I came across this type in the example code.

```
static inline int wl_data_device_add_listener(struct wl_data_device *wl_data_device,const struct wl_data_device_listener *listener, void *data)
{
    return wl_proxy_add_listener((struct wl_proxy *) wl_data_device,
                     (void (**)(void)) listener, data);
}
```

Comment: `(void (**)(void))` is a cast to a pointer to a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning no values.

Comment: Why you would want to do this cast is another question entirely.

Comment: I don't know the significance of variable pointer and function pointer conversion，uhhhhh

Comment: That cast won't pass through a code review and it looks like a likely candidate for invoking undefined behavior somewhere later down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void f(void)` is a function taking no arguments and returning void. `void (*p)(void)` is a pointer to such a function. `void (**pp)(void)` is a pointer to such a pointer. Then `void (**)(void)` is the type of `pp`.

Whether or not casting to this type in this situation is sensible is questionable.

Comment: One is a variable pointer and the other is a pointer to a function pointer. Where is the point of casting.

Comment: @pony That you have to ask your example code author. I contend that it is not sensible. I think this could even be UB in C (in C++ it would be).

Comment: @bitmask It definitely could be UB - that would depend on what a `struct wl_data_device_listener` actually contains.  Best case, though, is it's horribly confusing with a rank-as-a-dead-skunk code smell.